# Nginx: mod-security rule for http slow DoS attack

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service, nginx, mod-security

The only related rule in mod-security for slow DoS is `modsecurity_crs_11_slow_dos_protection`, and it's for Apache only.
Is there a rule for Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, NGINX does not include anything like to describe, but we can implement our own. As I understand Apache 2 modsecurity_crs_11_slow_dos_protection, limits the number of connections. [modsecurity_crs_11_slow_dos_protection](https://github.com/schubergphilis/mod_security/blob/master/templates/default/2.2.8/experimental_rules/modsecurity_crs_11_slow_dos_protection.conf.erb)

NGINX has a webpage, [Mitigating DDoS Attacks with NGINX and NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/) which mentions several methods for DDoS. Three ideas from their website come to mind:

**Limiting the Rate of Requests**

> You can limit the rate at which NGINX and NGINX Plus accept incoming
>   requests to a value typical for real users. For example, you might
>   decide that a real user accessing a login page can only make a request
>   every 2 seconds. You can configure NGINX and NGINX Plus to allow a
>   single client IP address to attempt to login only every 2 seconds
>   (equivalent to 30 requests per minute):
>
> ```
> limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;
>
> server {
>     # ...
>     location /login.html {
>         limit_req zone=one;
>     # ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The limit_req_zone directive configures a shared memory zone called
>   one to store the state of requests for the specified key, in this case
>   the client IP address ($binary_remote_addr). The limit_req directive
>   in the location block for /login.html references the shared memory
>   zone.

**Limiting the Number of Connections**

> You can limit the number of connections that can be opened by a single
>   client IP address, again to a value appropriate for real users. For
>   example, you can allow each client IP address to open no more than 10
>   connections to the /store area of your website:
>
> ```
> limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=addr:10m;
>
> server {
>     # ...
>     location /store/ {
>         limit_conn addr 10;
>         # ...
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The limit_conn_zone directive configures a shared memory zone called
>   addr to store requests for the specified key, in this case (as in the
>   previous example) the client IP address, $binary_remote_addr. The
>   limit_conn directive in the location block for /store references the
>   shared memory zone and sets a maximum of 10 connections from each
>   client IP address.

**Closing Slow Connections**

> You can close connections that are writing data too infrequently,
>   which can represent an attempt to keep connections open as long as
>   possible (thus reducing the server’s ability to accept new
>   connections). Slowloris is an example of this type of attack. The
>   client_body_timeout directive controls how long NGINX waits between
>   writes of the client body, and the client_header_timeout directive
>   controls how long NGINX waits between writes of client headers. The
>   default for both directives is 60 seconds. This example configures
>   NGINX to wait no more than 5 seconds between writes from the client
>   for either headers or body:
>
> ```
> server {
>     client_body_timeout 5s;
>     client_header_timeout 5s;
>     # ...
> }
> ```

Notice we only 'slow' connections for a DDoS, while DoS we need to mitigate by closing (or refusing) connections *we* deem malicious. Keep in mind the attack mitigations mentioned above are application layer DDoS mitigation. So, resources (CPU and Memory) are still be used. See, [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(networking)) and [IP suite (TCP/IP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) regarding resource usage, as resources are needed to encapsulate and de-encapsulate (frame -> packet (or datagram) -> segment -> PDU).